# login page in html/css error

Tags: html, css

This is the code i have written in html/css in eclipse(kepler) by making the dynamic web application.The error i get is in line:

```
<style type="text/css" scoped>
```

error name-invalid location of tag.

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <div style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; width: auto; max-width: 480px; background-color: #FFFFFF; border: 2px solid #D4D4D4; border-radius: 5px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #D4D4D4; margin: 50px auto auto;">
    <div style="background: #D4D4D4; border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px; padding: 15px;"><span style="font-family: verdana,arial; color: #D4D4D4; font-size: 1.00em; font-weight:bold;">HEY REGISTER NOW!</span></div>
    <div style="background: ; padding: 15px">
    <style type="text/css" scoped>
    td { text-align:left; font-family: verdana,arial; color: #000000; font-size: 1.00em; }
    input { border: 1px solid #CCCCCC; border-radius: 5px; color: #666666; display: inline-block; font-size: 1.00em;  padding: 5px; width: 100%; }
    input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"] { height: auto; width: auto; cursor: pointer; box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #D4D4D4; float: right; margin-top: 10px; }
    table.center { margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; }
    .error { font-family: verdana,arial; color: #000000; font-size: 1.00em; }
    </style>
<form method="post" action="crf.html" name="aform" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="login">
<input type="hidden" name="hide" value="">
<table class='center'>
<tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="login"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="password"></td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=2>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</div></div></div>
```

Please help me with an appropriate solution.

Comment: <div style="background: ; padding: 15px"> this looks wrong or is it just me?

Comment: i have already specified the error type.

Comment: You are right @DejaVu

Comment: @DejaVu is right. That is a problem. I dont know if it is THE problem though...

Comment: What is your `DOCTYPE` ?

Comment: @DejaVu is right, but also you haven't specified what error you're getting. `scoped` isn't really a widely supported attribute in HTML so I assume that's what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this format

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample Application</title>
<style type="text/css" scoped>
td {
    text-align: left;
    font-family: verdana, arial;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 1.00em;
}

input {
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #666666;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.00em;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}

input[type="button"],input[type="reset"],input[type="submit"] {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #D4D4D4;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

table.center {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.error {
    font-family: verdana, arial;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 1.00em;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <div
            style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; width: auto; max-width: 480px; background-color: #FFFFFF; border: 2px solid #D4D4D4; border-radius: 5px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #D4D4D4; margin: 50px auto auto;">
            <div
                style="background: #D4D4D4; border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px; padding: 15px;">
                <span
                    style="font-family: verdana, arial; color: #D4D4D4; font-size: 1.00em; font-weight: bold;">HEY
                    REGISTER NOW!</span>
            </div>
            <div style="background:; padding: 15px">

                <form method="post" action="crf.html" name="aform" target="_top">
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="login"> <input
                        type="hidden" name="hide" value="">
                    <table class='center'>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Username:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="login"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Password:</td>
                            <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan=2>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `style` tag within the `head` tags, not the `body`.

Also, this line:

```
<div style="background: ; padding: 15px">
```

Should be:

```
<div style="padding: 15px">
```

Or give it a background.

All your styles should go in a separate `.css` file, rather than inline/same file.

It looks fine here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J5R5N/1/)

Answer (score 0):

In:

- HTML 4 and Earlier
- XHTML 1.x
- HTML 5

The `<style>` element can only appear in the `<head>`

In:

- The WHATWG Living Standard for HTML
- HTML 5.1

The `<style>` element can appear in the `<body>` as well, but only if it has a `scoped` attribute and (IIRC) one or two other conditions are met.

---

Whatever tool you are using to test your markup with, is testing it against one of the languages in the first group (where it is not allowed) and not in the second group (where it is).

Given browser support for it, I would advise against using the scoped attribute at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

`scoped` isn't a widely supported attribute (believe it's oly natively available in Firefox at the moment), also you will need to specify the `DOCTYPE` as HTML5 for it to work. You have two choices, use a JavaScript library to get the tag working: https://github.com/thingsinjars/jQuery-Scoped-CSS-plugin

Or use conventional styling with classes, id's and appropriate CSS selectors.

More info here: http://html5doctor.com/the-scoped-attribute/